# Generate list from list of dictionary elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries of this type:

```
list: [{'attribute_categ_id': (1, u'Memory'), 'id': 1},   {'attribute_categ_id': (4, u'POLEAS'), 'id': 2}, {'attribute_categ_id': (6, u'CAPACIDAD'), 'id': 3}]
```

and I would like to get the list of ids of value

```
attribute_categ_id
```

in this example, I need this:

```
list=[1,4,6]
```

please, how can I do it?

Comment: Try `[c_dict['attribute_categ_id'][0] for c_dict in data]`

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension.

```
>>> l = [{'attribute_categ_id': (1, u'Memory'), 'id': 1},   {'attribute_categ_id': (4, u'POLEAS'), 'id': 2}, {'attribute_categ_id': (6, u'CAPACIDAD'), 'id': 3}]
>>> [i['attribute_categ_id'][0] for i in l]
[1, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = [{'attribute_categ_id': (1, u'Memory'), 'id': 1},   {'attribute_categ_id': (4, u'POLEAS'), 'id': 2}, {'attribute_categ_id': (6, u'CAPACIDAD'), 'id': 3}]
>>> [x['attribute_categ_id'][0] for x in my_list]
[1, 4, 6]
>>>
```